# Database design query: combine tables or keep separate?

Tags: database-design

I'm starting to design a database driven website.

I have two similar tables, `GPU vendor` and `CPU vendor`. Both have the same columns: `id, vendor_name, vendor_url, vendor_bio`.

Would you make separate tables or combine them, perhaps adding a type `column`?

I don't want my inexperience to hinder my design later on. Think first, do later! :)

Comment: good to see you atleast thought of getting a clarification. I've came across so many 'legacy' systems having db schemas that seems like being created on the fly.

Comment: I imagine that things get quite hairy when you come to modify databases years later!

Comment: I hear you. 3 years down the line its easier to add a table than add a column to existing table. 3 _more_ years down the line YAU would be pulling his hair why are there two tables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAU outlined the answer.  In most cases like yours, I have combined the two tables into one, with a type column to indicate which type each entry belongs to.

It depends on how you will use the data.  If many of your queries will combine rows from GPU types with rows from CPU types, then the single table table will yield better results.  If almost all your queries are exclusively about GPU types or exclusively about CPU types,  then you'll get better results from the two table design.

Ultimately, this boils down to what YAU said:  are they two entities or one entity.

I'm going to add that, either way, you can build one or two views that make the data look the other way.  If you create a single VENDORS table,  you can create a CPU_VENDORS view that only selects the CPU types and a GPU_VENDORS view that only selects the GPU types.  You can then access those views when convenient.

If you adopt a two table design,  you can create a single VENDORS view that is the UNION of GPU_VENDORS and CPU_VENDORS, and use that when needed.

Except for performance effects,  you'll get the best of both worlds out of the views.

Comment: I have a related question: let's say I go with combining the tables and have a type column to differentiate between 'cpu_vendor' and 'gpu_vendor'. What if I have a cpu_vendor that sells cpus **and** gpus? Do I have two entries for the same vendor (obviously not) or do I have an entry in type that is 'cpu/gpu'?

Comment: LK,  you can answer your related question by asking whether the vendor fields taken together are a candidate key, or whether you have to add in the type field to get a candidate key.  Unfortunately, the widespread practice of assigning every table an automunber id field reduces the relational model of data to a graph model of data with indirect addressing.

Answer (score 4):

If they are actually 'Vendor' in problem domain. I'll create a table 'VENDOR' and add column 'VENDOR_TYPE' along with your other columns.

```
Table Vendor{
    id, 
    vendor_type,
    vendor_name, 
    vendor_url, 
    vendor_bio    
}
```

But if they are two logically different Entity types, i would lean towards creating two separate tables. In your case it seems to be 'VENDOR' rather than 'GPUVendor' and 'CPUVendor'